# Compare difference of two array in php

Tags: php, arrays, compare

```
Array ( [34] => A [35] => B [36] => B [37] => C ) //This is the Answer
```

Compares

```
Array ( [34] => B [35] => C [36] => A [37] => D ) //This is the right data
```

I have tried `array_diff_key` and `array_diff` functions but both only returns

```
Array()
```

I would like to get the count of the difference, is there a faster way?

What did i do wrong? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
count(array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php).

```
<?php

$array1 = array('34' => 'A', '35' => 'B', '36' => 'B', '37' => 'C');
$array2 = array('34' => 'B', '35' => 'C', '36' => 'A', '37' => 'D');
$count = count(array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2));

echo $count; //4

?>
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/Zzilrn9C

Comment: I edited my answer, array_diff() don't work with your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array ( [34] => A [35] => B [36] => B [37] => C ) 
$array2 = array( [34] => B [35] => C [36] => A [37] => D ) 
$c = count(array_diff($array1, $array2));
echo $c;
```

This should work for you.